# Find logged on user and network home directory with a bash script

Tags: terminal, bash, user-account, network-user

I am trying to use a script to find the username and home directory of the user that is currently logged on to a Mac. This is what I have, and it works, but is there a better (i.e. simpler) way to do it?

```
user=`logname`
userHome="eval echo ~`echo $user`"
userHome=`$userHome`
```

The script will almost definitely not be run by the logged on user.

This is Mac OS X 10.6, joined to an Active Directory, and a network user is logged on. So the username does not appear in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script:

```
#!/bin/bash
w -h | sort -u -t' ' -k1,1 | while read user etc
do
  homedir=$(dscl . -read /Users/$user NFSHomeDirectory | cut -d' ' -f2)
  echo =$user= =$homedir=
done
```

will do the following:

- find all users logged in (via ssh too!) `w -h` or can use the `who` command too
- sort and find unique users `sort -u -t' ' -k1,1`
- for each logged user

  - read username
  - find his home directory from the DirectoryService daemon via the command  `dscl`
  - print out username and his home directory

Comment: Good old `dscl` ... don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 2):

The user is stored in a variable USER, and the home is in HOME:

```
echo user name: $USER, user home: $HOME
```

This is done automatically. You don't have to write any script to get them.

Comment: This will only tell me the username and home of the user that runs the script. I want the user that is logged on to the GUI, the script is running as a different user.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

From [this Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html#CSPARENS) I learned that

> The $(...) form has superseded backticks for command substitution.
>
> The $(...) form of command substitution permits nesting.

Now I am using:

```
user=$(logname)
userHome=$(eval echo ~$(echo $user))
```

Comment: That is cleaner than userHome=$(dscl . -read /Users/`logname` NFSHomeDirectory | awk '{print $2}) ; user=$(basename $userHome) - nicely done

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `logname` works, then you can get the home directory like this:

```
user=$(logname)
userHome=$(awk -F: -v u=$user '$1 == u {print $6}' /etc/passwd)
```

Comment: The user does not appear in `/etc/passwd/`. I updated the question.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if all the other complications are needed.

```
echo $USER
echo ~
```

Comment: From the post "The script will almost definitely not be run by the logged on user." -- your answer won't work to _discover_ other users on the system.